# R: Using a for loop to partially match levels of a factor to a character string?

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have a dataset of plots and subplots in which I measured tree species presence. I am trying to run through the data and identify which species were present at each of the plot-subplot combinations.

I've succeeded in creating a dataframe that identifies which species are present in each plot-subplot combination, but am now trying to append columns for each species with indicator variables (values of 1) that show their presence.

The initial code/data.frame looks as such:

```
f = aggregate(Species ~ Subplot + Plot, data = live.trees, 
              FUN=function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=', '))

a=rep(0, 35)
b=cbind(a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a)
colnames(b) = levels(live.trees$Species)
freq = as.data.frame(cbind(f, b))

Species = as.factor(live.trees$Species)

#Only showing 2 of 7 plots here...

freq[1:10,]
   Subplot Plot                    Species AA AM AO BC BG BP EA RA RM SH XG XM
1        1    1                         RA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2        2    1 EA, BP, XM, BC, AA, XG, RA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3        3    1         EA, XG, AA, AM, RA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4        4    1             AA, XM, RA, EA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5        5    1             EA, BC, RA, AA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6        1    2             XM, BC, RA, AM  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7        2    2                     RM, RA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8        3    2                 XM, BC, RA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9        4    2                     RA, XM  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10       5    2     XM, XG, AA, BC, BG, RA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I am now trying to write a for loop that runs through the table and pastes a "1" in each of the individual species columns (AA, AM, AO, etc.) if the two character string for species is matched under the freq$Species column. The for loop code I have crafted so far is:

```
#Manually going through and assigning a 1 value for each species 
#using a partial string match with grepl()

    for(k in 1:nrow(freq))
  if(grepl("AA", freq$Species[[k]]) == "TRUE")
    (freq$AA[k] = 1) else
    if(grepl("AM", freq$Species[[k]]) == "TRUE")
      (freq$AM[k] = 1) else
        if(grepl("AO", freq$Species[[k]]) == "TRUE")
          (freq$AO[k] = 1) else
            if(grepl("BC", freq$Species[[k]]) == "TRUE")
              (freq$BC[k] = 1)
                  #.... etc. (cutting off here to save space)
```

The code works to a degree, but is overwriting each previous Species column, and is also quite clunky.

```
Subplot Plot                    Species AA AM AO BC BG BP EA RA RM SH XG XM
1        1    1                         RA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2        2    1 EA, BP, XM, BC, AA, XG, RA  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3        3    1         EA, XG, AA, AM, RA  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4        4    1             AA, XM, RA, EA  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5        5    1             EA, BC, RA, AA  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6        1    2             XM, BC, RA, AM  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7        2    2                     RM, RA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8        3    2                 XM, BC, RA  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9        4    2                     RA, XM  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10       5    2     XM, XG, AA, BC, BG, RA  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

How do I:

1) Get the for loop to stop overwriting species presence indicators in prior columns?

2) Write the for loop in a more elegant manner? I thought I could create a factor variable called "Species" and loop over the elements of that (within the first for loop)... however my novice-rated experience started showing.

Any help or suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

I know that this is not a reproducible example, but am looking for general suggestions or tips that might help point me in the right direction. I will try to find a default dataset within R that I can coerce to replicate my troubles in the mean time.

Thank you in advance!

**Note:** The Species column was created as a string and is thus of class character.

Comment: The earlier/post somehow slipped past me. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: The next step - summing the values for each species within each plot - is also stumping me. I can do it species by species with aggregate()

    `aggregate(AA ~ Plot, data=freq, sum)`

However, I'm not sure of a more elegant way of doing so for all species at once. I imagine there's a means of using sapply to do this also, but R is throwing errors at my attempts...

@akrun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(qdapTools)
res <- cbind(freq[1:3], mtabulate(strsplit(freq$Species, ', ')))
rowsum(res[,4:ncol(res)], group= res$Plot)
#  AA AM BC BG BP EA RA RM XG XM
#1  4  1  2  0  1  4  5  0  2  2
#2  1  1  3  1  0  0  5  1  1  4
```

Or

```
aggregate(.~Plot, res[c(2,4:ncol(res))], FUN=sum)
#   Plot AA AM BC BG BP EA RA RM XG XM
#1    1  4  1  2  0  1  4  5  0  2  2
#2    2  1  1  3  1  0  0  5  1  1  4
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
res %>%
   group_by(Plot) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum), 4:ncol(res))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(res)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by =Plot, .SDcols=4:ncol(res)]
```

#### data

```
freq <- structure(list(Subplot = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L), Plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Species = c("RA", 
"EA, BP, XM, BC, AA, XG, RA", "EA, XG, AA, AM, RA", "AA, XM, RA, EA", 
"EA, BC, RA, AA", "XM, BC, RA, AM", "RM, RA", "XM, BC, RA", "RA, XM", 
"XM, XG, AA, BC, BG, RA"), AA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), AM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    AO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BC = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BG = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BP = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), EA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), RA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), RM = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), SH = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), XG = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), XM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    )), .Names = c("Subplot", "Plot", "Species", "AA", "AM", 
"AO", "BC", "BG", "BP", "EA", "RA", "RM", "SH", "XG", "XM"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: The OP provided only partial dataset.  In the full dataset, this should match the result

Comment: Also very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @jbukoski I updated the post.  Can you check whether that is what you want?

Comment: Perfect. For my purposes, however, there's no need to sum the Plot column (i.e. c(4:ncol(res)) rather than c(2,4:ncol(res)) ). Minor point though, thanks for the help!

Comment: @jbukoski  Updated with data.table and dplyr methods also.